# Update a struct value using a function that relies upon values in the struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct example_Type{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} exampleType;

void foo(exampleType* exampleStruct){
    exampleStruct->z = "value from exampleStruct, variable x" + "value from exampleStruct, variable y";

}

int main(){
    exampleType struct1;
    struct1.x = 10;
    struct2.y = 5;
    foo(&struct1);
}
```

How should I go about this?

```
exampleStruct->z = exampleStruct.y + exampleStruct.x;
```

Would this work? I want to call on the values found in x and y, but how do I do that?

Comment: What in the world is `exampleStruct->z = "value from exampleStruct, variable x" + "value from exampleStruct, variable y";`? `z` is an `int` and not a `char*`

Comment: @CoolGuy The edit on the first word was not needed, IMHO. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement

> exampleStruct->z = "value from exampleStruct, variable x" + "value from exampleStruct, variable y";

can be re-written as

> "value from exampleStruct, variable z" = "value from exampleStruct, variable x" + "value from exampleStruct, variable y";

If you think you can make use of `exampleStruct->z` inside `foo()`, then why not `exampleStruct->x` and `exampleStruct->y`? They are the member of the same structure variable. It'll work for sure. Try writing

```
exampleStruct->z = exampleStruct->x + exampleStruct->y;
```

Comment: This answer is a very nice example on how a good answer to a newbies question might be crafted! You'd make a good teacher ... :-)

Comment: @alk Thank you for the compliments sir. :-)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, Thank you very much! Sorry for the late response as I found the answer through my professor and don't regularly use stackexchange. Your answer really helps me with the logic of using pointers, so I really do appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
exampleStruct->z = exampleStruct->y + exampleStruct->x;
```

instead of

```
exampleStruct->z = exampleStruct.y + exampleStruct.x;
```

The `->` operator dereferences its left operand, then accesses one
of the members of the referenced object. So, the above statement is the same as doing

```
(*exampleStruct).z = (*exampleStruct).y + (*exampleStruct).x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this:

```
exampleStruct->z = exampleStruct->y+exampleStruct->x;
```

Note: you're using a pointer, thus, a `->` will be used instead of `.` while accessing the elements.

---

```
type_name x;
```

Creates a variable of type `type_name`

```
type_name *y;
```

Creates a *pointer* to variable of type `type_name`.

---

While using `struct`s you need to do like this with pointers:

```
struct smth *test;

test->a=0;
strncpy(test->word,"hello",5);
```

While you use plain structs (no pointers), you do:

```
struct smth test;

test.a=0;
strncpy(test.word,"hello",5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
exampleStruct->z = exampleStruct->x + exampleStruct->y;
```

You are getting the structure as a pointer.